# Include sap.tnt (SideNavigation) SAPUI5

Tags: sapui5, bootstrapping

I've created a view, which contain a SideNavigation. For this I needed to include the sap.tnt package. In the `index.html` I initialized the application like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <meta http-equiv='Content-Type' content='text/html;charset=UTF-8'/>

        <link href="./resources/css/dashboard.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <script src="resources/sap-ui-core.js"
                id="sap-ui-bootstrap"
                data-sap-ui-libs="sap.ui.commons, sap.tnt, sap.viz"
                data-sap-ui-theme="sap_goldreflection">
        </script>
        <!-- add sap.ui.table,sap.ui.ux3 and/or other libraries to 'data-sap-ui-libs' if required -->

        <script>
                sap.ui.localResources("dashboard");
                var view = sap.ui.view({id:"idHome1", viewName:"dashboard.Home", type:sap.ui.core.mvc.ViewType.JS});
                view.placeAt("content");
        </script>
    </head>
    <body class="sapUiBody" role="application">
        <div id="content"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

But I get still this error:

```
sap-ui-core.js: GET http://localhost:8080/Dashboard_PROTOTYP/resources/sap/tnt/library-preload.json 404 (Not Found)

sap-ui-core.js: 2016-05-30 09:53:13.899110 failed to preload 'sap.tnt.library-preload': Not Found -  sap.ui.ModuleSystem

sap-ui-core.js:71 GET http://localhost:8080/Dashboard_PROTOTYP/resources/sap/tnt/library.js 404 (Not Found)

ncaught Error: failed to load 'sap/tnt/library.js' from resources/sap/tnt/library.js: 404 - Not Found

sap-ui-core.js:152 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'SideNavigation' of undefined
```

I don't know what to do, because I've already included the library .... Anyone an idea?

Comment: which SAPUI5 version you  are using?

Comment: 1.36.9 , but this version should support sap.tnt :( I putted also https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/sdk/resources/sap-ui-core.js into the source, than it works, but it needs 3.64 seconds to load the DOM... normally it needs 0.64 seconds to load :/